# Flutter: how to call dart code from native (swift, kotlin)?

Tags: flutter, dart, platform, flutter-method-channel

I know it is possible and maybe common to call native code from dart via method channel, but does it works both ways (how to call a method which is written in dart from kotlin or swift)?

Comment: yes it works both ways: from native you call e method, from dart you have to set method call handler

Comment: @pskink can you share some example or maybe you have link to documentations?

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/MethodChannel-class.html and https://api.flutter.dev/javadoc/io/flutter/plugin/common/MethodChannel.html

Comment: @pskink that would definitely help me, thanks a lot!

Comment: Here's a complete example I used for a talk a few years ago: https://github.com/richardheap/audio_worklet